# Automating migration from Matrix to Grid and Playa to Relationships?

Tags: matrix, playa, relationships, grid

I've just upgraded to EE 2.7.0 and I am thinking about migrating my use of Matrix to Grid and my use of Playa to Relationships. The main reason is that since I run more than one site off my EE install, using Grid and Relations would allow me to implement such fields on all sites, instead of just one since I only have a single license each for Matrix and Playa.

Moving manually would be a bit time consuming, especially when it comes to my Matrix implementation, so I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions for how to automate the process? I do own Solspace's Importer module, but I am not sure if it would be useable in this scenario.

Comment: Concerning the Playa->Relationships migration Derek Hogue wrote a short and easy php-script, here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/21425/how-to-move-all-playa-relationship-to-ee-relationships

Answer (score 1):

In short: this is a doozy. Writing a routine to migrate a Playa field to a Relationship field wouldn't be too bad. But Matrix → Grid is another level - especially depending on what kind of columns you have in those Matrix fields (and if their fieldtypes are even Grid-compatible yet).

My guess would be that it's cheaper for you to license your additional sites at $118 a piece than spend many frustrating hours attempting to migrate your existing data. Or just use Grid and Relationship fields going forward and leave what's in-place as it is.

Comment: My use of Matrix is fairly simplistic, on the whole. Its a three-column setup with File, Text, Text. Does that still sound like a bad idea? I suppose I should add that I haven't yet done (or seen) a good comparison of Matrix and Grid (or Playa and Relationships), so I am not quite sure what capabilities I'd be giving up on. It just seemed more sensible to use the same method on all sites, to lessen the chance of confusion.