# How to move all Playa relationship to EE relationships

Tags: playa, relationships

I need to move all playa relationships to EE relationships.

What is the best way to do this?
I have not been able to find anything online explaining a process or how to approach this.

All I know is I don't want to just change the field type.

Comment: Do you have any Playa relationships which were made inside of Matrix fields?

Comment: @DerekHogue No, the Playa relationships are separate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a pretty simple operation, since they are stored very similarly.

First, backup your database. Then, run this code in a PHP-enabled template:

```
<?php

$playa = ee()->db->query("SELECT * FROM exp_playa_relationships");
foreach($playa->result_array() as $rel)
{
    $data = array(
        'parent_id' => $rel['parent_entry_id'],
        'child_id' => $rel['child_entry_id'],
        'field_id' => $rel['parent_field_id'],
        'order' => $rel['rel_order']
    );
    ee()->db->query(
        ee()->db->insert_string('exp_relationships', $data)
    );
}

?>
```

Then, change your Playa fields to Relationships fields. Done.

Comment: Much simpler than I would have thought. Thanks @DerekHogue

Comment: Thanks from me also @derek-hogue for this simple solution! Question: Does this also work for EE3?

Comment: Yup, it should.

Comment: I just tried it with an EE2-install, and it works perfectly - thanks again!

Comment: This PHP script worked perfectly with EE 2.11.9. Had a channel with a Playa channel field associated with a Zoo Visitor member. The channel had about 2,500 entries. After using this PHP script, loading a single channel entry on the EE admin panel went from being 50 seconds to 2 seconds.