# convert EE relationships to Playa

Tags: playa, relationships, field-conversion

I guess the opposite of this [How to move all Playa relationship to EE relationships](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/21425/how-to-move-all-playa-relationship-to-ee-relationships)

previously developer used the relationships field that the client now wants to search over using Low Search. Obviously relationships just stores the entry id compared to Playa which also stores the entry title.

Is there a reverse method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always read the manual Steven!!! http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/using/converting/relationships.html