# EE3 Relationships VS Playa

Tags: playa, relationships

I know the EE3 Relationship fieldtype is now more powerful.

Does Playa 5 for EE3 still have advantages compared to the new EE3 Relationships?

Is Playa 5 worth it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used the latest Playa but the with relationships​ being native it will stop painful upgrades to the CMS whenever you next upgrade - it's almost always better to rely on core modules then to introduce 3rd party modules.

Also, if you want to switch to relationships then follow this simple guide: [How to move all Playa relationship to EE relationships](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/21425/166)

Comment: Hi Stuart! Thanks a lot for your fast reply, I would update my EE2 Playa version to the EE3 one, but as EE Relationships has evolved, I wondered if it was worthwhile to do an update. So I will use the native EE3 Relationships.  Regards, Stéphane

Comment: Added addendum to my previous reply.